# :hover не работает

Tags: css

Не работает hover

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.main>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

ul li * {
  display: none;
}

#menu1:hover#menu11 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu1">menu1
      <ul>
        <li id="menu11">menu1.1
          <ul>
            <li>menu1.1.1</li>
            <li>menu1.1.1</li>
            <li>menu1.1.1</li>
            <li>menu1.1.1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>menu1.1</li>
        <li>menu1.1</li>
        <li>menu1.1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>menu2</li>
    <li>menu3</li>
    <li>menu4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: пробел добавьте

Comment: @teran пробел да. но в целом не в этом ошибка

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых - надо писать:

```
#menu1:hover #menu11
            ^--- тут пробел
```

---

Во-вторых - когда ты написал вот так:

```
ul li * { 
    display: none; 
}
```

то ты скрыл **ВСЕ** элементы у родителя (ul li), в том числе и элементы `ul`.

Соответственно, когда ты пишешь

```
#menu1:hover #menu11{ display: block; }
```

то это говорит отобразиться лишь элементу `li#menu11`. При этом в этот же самый момент его родитель `ul` всё также `display: none;` и его потомок  `ul` всё также `display: none;`. А раз родитель невидим, то как может отобразиться ребенок? Никак. Поэтому нужно менять логику отображения у селекторов.

Не знаю всей задумки, но, возможно, тебе вместо `ul li * { ... }` надо написать просто `ul li li { ... }` –

Comment: но в этом случае я же обращаюсь к тому, что находится внутри элемента li а не к ul.

Comment: @ArtashesMuradyan разве я не ясно описал суть? :(  Ты сказал **ВСЕМ** элементам, чтобы они были `display: none;`.... а потом говоришь `li` элементу `#menu11` отобразиться `display: block;`, но при этом  в этот же самый момент его родитель `ul` имеет `display: none;`. и его потомок `ul` тоже имеет `display: none;`...  А раз родитель невидим, то как может отобразиться ребенок? Никак. Нужно обязательно чтобы был и родитель видим......например чтобы показать содержимое яйца, надо расколоть скорлупу... но если ты его не видишь как такового, то откуда ты это содержимое достанешь?)) ниоткуда

Comment: @ArtashesMuradyan не знаю всей задумки, возможно тебе надо написать просто `ul li li  {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: Спасибо, кажется дошло)